# Table cell width with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table with two columns, I would like the to set the width of each of these columns, for example left column 30% right column 70%. Eventually I will have hundreds of rows so If I can apply a global css class I guess that would be best?

Currently the left column is compressed and doesn't look good.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6s3ptku/) if somebody could lend some assistance.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>row name here</td>
                <td>sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer eget</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>another row name here</td>
                <td>sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer egetsdsdfsdf fsdfsdf</td>></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is my take on it. I've added an id to the table for easier access.

**The Markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="someid">
            <tr>
                <td>row name here</td>
                <td>sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer eget</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>another row name here</td>
                <td>sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer egetsdsdfsdf fsdfsdf</td>></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#someid tr td:nth-child(1){
    width:30%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/z6s3ptku/4/)

Answer (score 7):

when I tried with `width` property on first `td` of `tr` it works fine for me

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td width="30%">row name here</td>
                    <td width="70%">sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer eget</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>another row name here</td>
                    <td>sed auctor diam sollicitudin ut. Donec et sodales quam, eu vehicula urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer egetsdsdfsdf fsdfsdf</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As per latest update, width attribute in `td` will no longer supported, so you should set width through css.

```
#someid tr td{
    width:30%;
}
```

using psudo code:

```
#someid tr td:nth-child(1){
    width:30%;
}
```

whats the issue you faced?

Comment: @johnny_s no need, set it for first tr's td

Comment: use of width attribute is deprecated

Comment: @new_bee_magento check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td or http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp

Comment: It clearly says Note: Do not use this attribute in the latest standard: instead set the CSS width property. Not supported in HTML5.

Comment: +1 for helping me anyway @new_bee_magento although I'm accepting another answer as I think css is the best way to go ahead.

Comment: yes but it means we should avoid using such attributes

Comment: No it simply means that it will not be supported in future or wont work in future.

Comment: @new_bee_magento I just meant that it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the css property `table-layout: fixed` This will force the given width on the columns:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td:first-child {
    width: 30%;
}
td:last-child {
    width: 70%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6s3ptku/7/)

Normally you would give every cell in the column the same width but with `table-layout: fixed` you can set it only on the header cell of the column:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="first">Column A</th>
        <th class="second">Column B</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

As shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6s3ptku/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Define a min-width property for your with the class nowrap, like so:

```
td.nowrap {
  min-width: 129px;
}
```

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6s3ptku/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```css
table.table.table-striped tr > td:first-child {
    width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<style>

td{
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#someid tr td:nth-child(1){
    width:10%;
}

</style>



add id "somdeid" in table

<table id="someid">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>some text here</td>
<td>some long text here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```